# Faucet stem search

Tags: faucet

Does anyone know who makes this brass faucet stem? It goes on the shower wall

[image]

Comment: Show us the housing this was in. Probably there is a marker on it

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR Nothing beats walking up to a salesperson and saying "I want another one of these"

There are **many** different varieties. Without really clear identifying marks - brand name/logo, model #, part #, etc. - there is really no way to guess over the internet. If you can't shop in person then get some really good measurements of the various sections of the stem. But your best bet is to shop in person at:

- A plumbing supply house - these (like similar electric supply houses) are typically off the beaten path, often in a warehouse district or industrial zone, not in a shopping mall.
- An old-fashioned hardware store. Ideally one that is near home (or wherever this was installed) as sometimes you will find that 500 houses built 50 years ago all had the same brand of faucet installed and the local place knows *exactly* what you need. But if they don't know right away, they'll help you look through all the possible parts - they may have 1 or 2 of each of dozens of different possibilities, just waiting for you to walk through the door.
- A big box home improvement store (Home Depot, Lowes, etc.). These typically stock fewer types of replacement parts, but you may get lucky. If not, they may have a special order section with a catalog showing hundreds of different parts.

Comment: As noted, with good measurements you CAN figure out what replacement to get. 3 aspects are needed: length of stem, width of main barrel part of stem, and a count of the number of "teeth" on the end that holds the handle. There are databases/books that allow you to look up a replacement based on these values. man's answer's gist is right, though. These days it can be hard to find a local plumbing supply house that is not "wholesale customers only" - BTDT.

Comment: @Armand A lot of supply houses (plumbing, electrical, appliance, HVAC, etc.) are perfectly happy to sell to ordinary people except (a) higher price - often double, but on a $3 part that becomes $6 that really doesn't matter; (b) they will look for parts but they are *not* there to teach you about plumbing/electrical/HVAC/etc. and (c) there are limits - e.g., some restricted items (e.g., refrigerant) some just very complex or hard to install - but even then much of the time they'll say "OK, but sale is final".

Comment: Yes I agree but sadly have to report that after closures due to very high commercial rents in my area and the internet, remaining supply houses tend to have signs on the outside proclaiming "wholesale customers only". Hopefully that is not the case in most areas.